# Usage of the original class method after being decorated requires the object instance as parameter

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have the following code:
A decorator:

```
def pyDecorator(func):
    print func
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print args
        print kwargs
        tBegin = time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        tEnd = time()
        if result:
            # UI update
            print("\nTBegin '{}'({} s)".format(func.__name__,  tBegin))
            # UI and report update
            print("TEnd '{}' ({} s) ({} s) Result:{}".format(func.__name__, tEnd,tEnd - tBegin, result))  
        return result
    #workarround to use the original function
    wrapped._original=func 
    return wrapped
```

And a decorated class method:

```
class Dummy(object): 
    @pyDecorator
    def ClassMethod(self):
        print "Original class code executed"
        return True
```

If I call the method for the original function in the following way, I receive this error `"TypeError: ClassMethod() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given):"`

```
ClassInstance.ClassMethod._original()
```

So I am forced to use the following call:

```
ClassInstance.ClassMethod._original(ClassInstance)
```

Is it possible to do this as in the first way ? I do not understand why I should put the class instance as a parameter when it is already provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassInstance.ClassMethod._original` is a function not bound to any class instance.

Note that the transformation from function to method happens when a function object is accessed via a class instance, say, using dot reference. Here however, `_original` is only bound to another function object `wrapper` (elevated to a bound method at runtime) not to a class instance. An implicit `self` parameter is therefore not passed. You'll have to explicitly pass it.

```
ClassInstance.ClassMethod._original
^
|- instance   ^           
              |- method
                          ^
                          |- function object bound to method
```

---

> I do not understand why I should put the class instance as a parameter
>   when it is already provided

No, it's not already provided.

Comment: Actually there is not even *implicit `self` parameter*. Passing any argument will work because what you get is a function that takes one argument.

Comment: @sstyvane Yes, function with single argument. *Passing any argument will work*, well, if the argument implements the required interface (like a `Dummy` instance) as required by the function at runtime, although `self` is never used in the function here.